# evince uses the wrong path for my browser when I click on a link, how can I fix it?

Tags: nautilus, pdf, evince, default-browser

As the title say, I can see that the path evince uses is wrong.

I have SeaMonkey version 2.49.2, as evince is trying to use version 2.33.1.

I looked around and so far I can't see what evince would be using to open the browser. I also don't see an option in evince to change what browser it would be using.

[image]

Note that I understand that I may need to tweak apparmor to authorize my newer version, but obviously I don't want to allow 2.33.x to work. It's too old.

I found a couple of similar questions that talk a lot about apparmor. And the others, they talk about "defaults", but none that I've found so far have seamonkey in them (v2.33.1 or otherwise). So I'm not too sure where the heck evince is looking for that path!

I verified my nautilus attachment and it looks correct (i.e. if I open a .html from nautilus, it starts the correct version of SeaMonkey.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the file with a `find` + `grep` against all my .something folders:

```
find ~/.[a-z]* -type f -exec grep -Hn seamonkey-2.33 {} \;
```

This took at least 15 min., (I have slow hard drives, but I also have many files there...) but at least I found the following file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/userapp-SeaMonkey-QSF6ZX.desktop
```

Changing the reference to the newer version fixed that problem. I still have the problem with apparmor which the other posts answer as expected so I won't repeat that here.

*Now if you know why the filename is "userapp" dash "SeaMonkey" dash "QSF6ZX"... I'd be interested to hear from you!*